# Laravel RESTful Api - Erros em JSON ao invés de HTML

Tags: php, json, laravel, rest

Como faço para que o controller retorne automaticamente uma response para o cliente em formato JSON ao invés de HTML, em caso de erro (p. ex. erro 404, 500, 419, etc.). Por exemplo, caso dê erro 500 no Laravel, gostaria que retornasse da seguinte forma:

```
{status: 500,
 message: "Trying to get id os non object at UserController.php line 150"
 trace: {...}
}
```

Percebi que isso já é feito nas rotas da aplicação Web (web.php) ao fazer uma requisição interna em Ajax. 
Estou montando um aplicativo Android que faz requisições na minha aplicação Web, que está sendo utilizada como um Webservice, e não estou conseguindo tratar os erros, pois eles estão sendo retornados no formato HTML (document).
Desde já agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: ja tentou editar o App/Exception/handler? você pode modificar ele e retornar uma response com os dados que você quiser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tratar isso diretamente no method do seu controller, assim:

```
try {            
    //Código aqui, abaixo a variavel $data retorna o valor que vc quer consumir.

    return response()->json([
        'info' => 'success',
        'result' => $data
    ]);

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return response()->json([
        'info' => 'error',
        'result' => 'Não foi possível capturar os dados do usuário!.'
        'error' => $e->getMessage(),
    ], 400);
}
```

Coloque o try dentro do method, e dentro do try passe os dados que você quer mandar (onde está o comentário). No "return" dentro do try, a variável `$data` vai te retornar os dados que você quiser.

Onde você está vendo aí o número "400" é o error de acesso. Se preferir, pode mudar isso para, por exemplo, 500 ou 404.

Se der erro ele vai sair do try e vai entrar no catch, onde ele vai retornar a info "Error" e o result é a mensagem que você quiser. Se quiser retornar a mensagem que o próprio sistema gera, tira essa frase que coloquei no result "Não foi possível capturar os dados do usuário!." e coloca assim:

```
$e->getMessage()
```

Dai é só tratar onde você vai consumir. Também é possível adicionar validações, assim:

```
if(res.info == 'success'){
   $pegando_os_dados = res.result;
}else(res.info == 'error'){
   $error = res.result;
}
```

Você decide como vai apresentar o erro.

Answer (score 1):

**App/Exception/Handler.php**

Acho que desta forma você consegue fazer isso, faça um teste ai!

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($this->isHttpException($exception))
    {
        if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404)
            return response(['exception'=>$exception], 404);

        if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 500)
            return response(['exception'=>$exception], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```